# Confused about libraries

Tags: php, glib, cairo, freetype, harfbuzz

I was given a php project that needs to be implemented into a Drupal site I'm doing for a client. I'm confused about library dependancies for this code. The read me file sent to me said that it requiers:

```
freetype >= 2.3.12
 - pixman >= 0.18.0
 - cairo >= 1.8.10
 - glib >= 2.24.0
 - harfbuzz-ng (git master from git://git.freedesktop.org/~behdad/harfbuzz-ng)
```

Is installing the libraries on my computer the same as installing them for my XAMMP? To install them on my plesk dv do I just follow the Linux instructions for compiling and installing?

I'm not used to this type dependancies, am I on the right track at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the files in the computer which you may be using as a server. None of them looks like a php extension so my best guess is you may need to install them in the machine. Any file which appears to be an php extension goes into the xammp.